Getting syntax error for JOIN applied between two metrics
Writing first MQL query to achieve below:

reads log from a metric "logging.googleapis.com/user/count_verify_country" which has a field COUNTRY
reads log from another metric "logging.googleapis.com/user/verify_completed" which has a field
MESSAGE
Now, count all occurences with MESSAGE as "VERIFY COMPLETED" for all different COUNTRY

Note: both logs have a common field flowExecutionId whose value remains same for each transaction.
fetch logging.googleapis.com/user/count_verify_country
| filter has(jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.verify.country)
| group_by [jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.daVinciFlow.flowExecutionId], [country: any(jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.verify.country)]
| join (
    fetch logging.googleapis.com/user/verify_completed
    | filter jsonPayload.requestBody.success.message == "Verify Completed"
    | group_by [jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.daVinciFlow.flowExecutionId], [success_count: count_true()]
) on jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.daVinciFlow.flowExecutionId
| outer_join
| group_by [country], [total_success: sum(success_count)]```

Getting error: Line 5: Expected: ')'. Instead found: 'logging'.


You mentioned you want to count all occurrences of MESSAGE as SUCCESS. But you are giving “Verify Completed” when you are filtering the verify_completed logs. So try using the SUCCESS in place of Verify Completed at the line  filter jsonPayload.requestBody.success.message == "SUCCESS"  and outer_join is not required.
fetch logging.googleapis.com/user/count_verify_country
| filter has(jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.verify.country)
| group_by [jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.daVinciFlow.flowExecutionId], [country: any(jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.verify.country)]
| join (
    fetch logging.googleapis.com/user/verify_completed
    | filter jsonPayload.requestBody.success.message == "SUCCESS"
    | group_by [jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.daVinciFlow.flowExecutionId], [success_count: count()]
) on jsonPayload.requestBody.actors.client.daVinciFlow.flowExecutionId
| group_by [country], [total_success: sum(success_count)]

Refer to this official MQL example document for more information.

Hey, thanks for your response. My bad, was trying to break the task into steps and wrote "SUCCESS" instead of "VERIFY COMPLETED" as latter appears in the logs.
I tried removing outer join, but still getting same error for the second fetch statement.
Line 6: Expected: ')'. Instead found: 'logging_bucket'

Can you update the question with latest error and the changes you done to the query?

Unable to add whole query under the comment, but its same as above, only removed outer_join as you suggested. And got the error as mentioned in previous comment
Line 5: Expected: ')'. Instead found: 'logging'.

Can you try by giving count() instead of count_true()

Doesn't make any sense. The error is next to the join statement, somehow it is expecting braces to be closed. It is syntax issue, not variable definition
